# Equivalent of module.exports in Typescript Declaration file

Tags: typescript

I try to do the declaration file of a library.

In the `library.js` file there is:

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' /* && !!module.exports*/) {
    module.exports = Library;
}
```

What should I put in my `library.d.ts` file to be able to import and use this library in my code?

I expect to be able to do:

```
import { Library } from 'library';
const instance = new Library();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use this syntax in the case of `export =`:

```
import Library = require("library");
```

More about it here: [export = and import = require()](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require)

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the special `export =` and `import Library = require` syntax, as pointed out by @Nitzan:

[export = and import = require()](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require)

---

A complete example:

**`node_modules/library/index.js`**

```
module.exports = function(arg) {
  return 'Hello, ' + arg + '.';
}
```

**`library.d.ts`** *This filename technically does not matter, only the `.d.ts` extension.*

```
declare module "library" {
  export = function(arg: string): string;
}
```

**`source.ts`**

```
import Library = require('library');

Library('world') == 'Hello, world.';
```

Comment: I'm getting an `'{' expected` error on the `export = function ...` example...

Comment: @Andy Did you forget a `{`?

Comment: it's expecting a function body starting with `{`, which isn't present in your example.  It doesn't seem to like a function declaration without a body after `export =`.  The only workaround I've found so far is to declare `function foo(arg: string): string;` above and then `export = foo;`.

Comment: Unfortunately the link for `export =` syntax doesn't include documentation about type declarations within `declare module`.  I'm not sure if the grammar has been changed since your answer.

Comment: @Andy What I have posted is a fully working example. The syntax has not changed. Adding and exporting other types does complicate the syntax slightly I think. Checkout https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html